# What place is this?

Tags: riddle, word, lateral-thinking, geography, steganography

The following text is a clue and will lead to a place on earth. The answer will be one word containing eight characters.

> **Can Heaven flush its Gates as innocent Kisses, then must we all take Heed, and bad Strumpets shall aske for Balm.**

> Where are we going?

Comment: It doesn't *look* like a rebus, but I guess I'd have to see the answer..

Comment: Are the capitals in the words intentional?

Comment: The capitals are intentional, yes.

Comment: I feel like the capitals are part of the place's name

Comment: I would say it is a Shakespearean cipher. Anyone here familiar with this way of hiding text in text?

Comment: Meaning changing every letter with the letter that comes four letters later?

Comment: @CarloTheBouncer , aske or ask ? is *aske* a clue ?

Comment: I've got a lead saying the location is somewhere in South Sudan. One of the creators of this riddle recently checked in to Juba on Facebook, the capital of this country, as both a joke and a lead. The city is known for its problems with prostitution (Strumpets). Maybe the words themselves represent the place?

Answer (score 14):

We are going to

> [Chukudum, South Sudan](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chukudum)

Start at the first letter of the text: **C**.  This is first letter of the solution and the key that points to the next letter in the solution.  C is the third letter of the alphabet, so move ahead three spaces in the text, ignoring spaces and punctuation.  This gives you **H**, which is the second letter in the solution.  H is the 8th letter of the alphabet, so now move 8 spaces, to **U**.  Continue on in this way, and you get the letters **CHUKUDUM**.

It appears the uppercase letters are simply a red herring, and the unusual spelling of "aske" serves to make the spacing correct for the last **M**.

Location of the letters:

> **C**an **H**eaven fl**u**sh its Gates as innocent **K**isses, then m**u**st we all take Heed, and ba**d** Str**u**mpets shall aske for Bal**m**.

Answer (score 4):

> The capitalized words (except the initial 'C' in 'Can') are all nouns, but there's just six of them. There's no pattern in their initial characters. First letters: HGKESB, second letters: EAIETA. Third letters: ATSERL. Fourth letters: VESDUM. Last letters: NSSDSM.

Also,

> Since we're looking for a word containing *eight* characters, the six highlighted nouns might be a hint, but not part of the final solution.

And,

> There's also something strange going on in the wording of things like "then must we all" and the extra 'e' in "shall aske".

Comment: I see chgkhsb or hgkhsb as the capitals - no E. And what do you mean by highlighted vowels?